# Daily cron running, But can't find file

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-16.04

I wrote simple shell script for backup mysql and send it to my email few months ago, It works very well even now, I can get packed sql file on my mailbox everyday.

Today I am going to change mail address to another, so I ssh into webserver. and simply type `cd /etc/cron.daily` But, there is no file I wrote before. I checked `ls -al`, `cron.d`, `cron.hourly`, `cron.weekly`, `cron.monthly`... But none of them has the script.

In this situation, I don't know what's happening now How could I find it?

Comment: Your cron daemon typically logs all jobs that are run and should point you in the correct direction. Note that in addition to the system cron entries you may also have personal cron tab files ; `crontab -e ` and `crontab -e -u username`

Comment: The cron log (/var/log/cron or /var/log/syslog on Ubuntu) has all commands executed by cron.  Usually the user crontabs are saved in /var/spool/cron/